# Problems enabling hyper-v for Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, docker-for-windows, docker

Does anyone have any ideas how to enable Hyper-v and containers on Windows 10 Pro 64bit with compatible hardware (according to msinfo32) and all requirements met ie BIOS virtualisation enabled, >4GB RAM and so on. Despite all this none of the commands in powershell or cmd succeed. They complain that one or more parent features must be enabled. There is no error when enabling via Windows features but after the restart Hyper-v regresses to disabled. This question seems to come up a lot and I have tried a wide range of “solutions” but no fix so far. My main goal here is to run Docker for Windows.

Comment: Hyper-V is incompatible with other virtualisation technologies such as Virtual Box (used by old docker setups). If you installed other virtualisation technologies at any time in the past you have to remove them first before you can enable Hyper-V.

Comment: Yes, I know. Unfortunately I don't have any alternative virtualisation installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with Windows Defender Fresh start. Not ideal but not as bad as a full reinstall. Worked immediately after this.